# How do I test ajax POST request with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, xmlhttprequest

I just want to test ajax request on controller spec. The product code is below. I'm using Devise for authentication.

```rb
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if request.xhr?
      @note = Note.new(params[:note])
      if @note.save
        render json: { notice: "success" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And spec is below.

```rb
describe NotesController do
  before do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user.confirm!
    sign_in user
  end

  it "has a 200 status code" do
    xhr :post, :create, note: { title: "foo", body: "bar" }, format: :json
    response.code.should == "200"
  end
end
```

I expect the response code to be 200, but it returns 401. I guess it must be because the request which rspec throws lacks authenticity_token or something. How can I stub it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 37):

Answering my own question. I found that `format: :json` was wrong. Just delete it and it works. Just like below:

```rb
it "has a 200 status code" do
  xhr :post, :create, note: { title: "foo", body: "bar" }
  response.code.should == "200"
end
```

I'm sorry for all the fuss.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution. I don't like using `format: json` when the request is a generic xhr.

Comment: Note: with Rails 5 and newer rspec, the non-deprecated form of this would be: `post :create, xhr: true, params: { note: { title: "foo", body: "bar" } }`.  In future versions, the keyword params will be required and `xhr` method will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I moved format: :json into params hash and it works fine, responding with json.

```
describe NotesController do
  before do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user.confirm!
    sign_in user
  end

  it "has a 200 status code" do
   xhr :post, :create, { note: { title: "foo", body: "bar" }, format: :json } 
   response.code.should == "200"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -4):

You've probably met CSRF error, try to disable CSRF validation for ajax calls, something like

```
# In your application_controller.rb
def verified_request?
  if request.xhr?
    true
  else
    super()
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this tip but it didn't make any change. And I feel little uneasy setting csrf verify off by the way.

Comment: -1 disabling CSRF protection is NOT a solution to this problem.