# How do I resolve "bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)"? Ruby on Rails, Michael Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) by Michael Hartl.

I reached [Chapter 11.37](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code-relationships_controller_spec_ajax) but my test is failing. I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
ArgumentError:
bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
```

I'm new to Ruby on Rails so I don't really know what's going wrong. Can someone help resolve this error?

controllers/relationships_controller.rb:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

features/relationships_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RelationshipsController, type: :request do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

  describe "creating a relationship with Ajax" do

    it "should increment the Relationship count" do
      expect do
        xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
      end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "should respond with success" do
      xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end

  describe "destroying a relationship with Ajax" do

    before { user.follow!(other_user) }
    let(:relationship) { user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user) }

    it "should decrement the Relationship count" do
      expect do
        xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
      end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "should respond with success" do
      xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your stacktrace down to where it hits your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The version](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior/xhr) of `xhr` that this tutorial depends on, which takes a method as the second argument, is from `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`. That module is only included for *controller* or *view* tests by the rspec-rails gem. You are picking up [another version of `xhr`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers/xhr) from Rails, with expects a path as the second argument, hence the error you're getting.

You need to make sure that your test is of type `controller` by including it in the `controllers` directory or setting the test type explicitly. Because you have the test in the *features* directory and not otherwise typed, it's not considered a *controller* test. (Note: Figure 11.37 in the tutorial does have the test residing in the `spec/controllers` directory.)

Comment: Your eyes are so sharp to find `features` directory in question.

Comment: @BillyChan I wish they had been. ;-) I only thought to look for it after searching the rspec-rails code for references to the module in question.

Answer (score 3):

xhr method [seems to receive a path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers/xhr) instead of an action name. So it should work if you replace by

```
xhr :post, relationships_path, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
```

Comment: Wow. That's a significant discrepancy in the tutorial. I've seen `xhr` documented with a method symbol as the second argument as well, though, at least in the RSpec context. I wonder if something has changed or if there are multiple versions.

Comment: See the relatively recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118205/how-do-i-test-ajax-post-request-with-rspec for an example where a method in the second argument works fine, for example.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin rspec [doesn't seems to have a xhr method](http://apidock.com/rspec/search?query=xhr), but maybe there are more than one xhr method on Rails?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Maybe is just undocumented

Comment: There are two aliases and two underlying methods with the same name.  Here's the one that matches the tutorial http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior/xhr

Comment: Just letting you know I added a separate answer. I hope you think that was appropriate. :-)

Comment: +1 for usefulness in tracking down the duplicate xhr methods.