# Cover format.json with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

I want to know how do I test this format.json from my Controller on rspec. Here is the code I want to cover:

Controller:

```
def edit
  @ngo = Ngo.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if request.xhr? 
      if params[:zipcode] 
        format.json { render json: Address.new(Correios::CEP::AddressFinder.get(params[:zipcode]))}
      end
    else
      @phones = Hash[@ngo.phones.map {|phone| [phone.id.to_s ,phone.phone_number]}]
      @phones = @phones.to_json
      format.html 
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried some ways but with no success. Anyone knows how I do? Thanks :)

Comment: It would be helpful to show us, what you have tried and did not work.

Comment: I've tried to get any response from json with 
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq('1231')
but I really don't know what I'm doing tbh.

Comment: You didn't show your spec code... But usually the similar problem is in missed [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views) in spec file. The reason: RSpec tries to speedup tests and does not render response by default.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you. It involved me doing a couple things I've never tried before such as `xhr :post, :edit` and the module inheritance .get call but I think it looks right. Let me know if this works!

```
# spec/controllers/some_controller_spec.rb

describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  context "#edit" do
    it "renders address as json" do
      ngo = double(:ngo, id: "1")
      correios_obj = double(:correios_obj)
      json_address = double(:json_address)
      expect(Ngo).to receive(:find).with("1").and_return(ngo)
      expect(Correios::CEP::AddressFinder).to receive(:get).with("35950").and_return(correios_obj)
      expect(Address).to receive(:new).with(correios_obj).and_return(json_address)
      xhr :post, :edit, zipcode: "35950", id: "1"
      expect(response.body).to eq json_address
    end
  end
end
```

Also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118205/how-do-i-test-ajax-post-request-with-rspec) helped me with the xhr part